# Map[String,Any] to compact json string using json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I am currently extracting some metrics from different data sources and storing them in a map of type `Map[String,Any]` where the key corresponds to the metric name and the value corresponds to the metric value. I need this to be more or less generic, which means that values types can be primitive types or lists of primitive types.

I would like to serialize this map to a JSON-formatted string and for that I am using `json4s` library. The thing is that it does not seem possible and I don't see a possible solution for that. I would expect something like the following to work out of the box :)

```
val myMap: Map[String,Any] = ...    // extract metrics
val json = myMap.reduceLeft(_ ~ _)  // create JSON of metrics
```

Navigating through [source code](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/scala_2.10/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonDSL.scala) I've seen `json4s` provides implicit conversions in order to transform primitive types to `JValue`'s and also to convert `Traversable[A]/Map[String,A]/Option[A]` to `JValue`'s (under the restriction of being available an implicit conversion from `A` to `JValue`, which I understand it actually means `A` is a primitive type). The `~` operator offers a nice way of constructing `JObject`'s out of `JField`'s, which is just a type alias for `(String, JValue)`.

In this case, map values type is `Any`, so implicit conversions don't take place and hence the compiler throws the following error:

```
                    value ~ is not a member of (String, Any)
[error]             val json = r.reduceLeft(_ ~ _)
```

Is there a solution for what I want to accomplish?

Comment: If I understand you correctly and you would only like to serialize `myMap`, why not call `Serialization.write(myMap)` directly?

Comment: @user3567830 I want a JSON string representation of `myMap`, that's the purpose of using a JSON scala library such as `json4s`

Comment: Yes, `org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write(myMap)` does exactly that. (I used the jackson version of json4s, but this should work for the native version as well).

Comment: @user3567830 This are great news (missed the Serialization chapter when reading the docs, too much scrolling :D). Please feel free to post your answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since you are actually only looking for the JSON string representation of `myMap`, you can use the `Serialization` object directly. Here is a small example (if using the native version of json4s change the import to `org.json4s.native.Serialization`):

**EDIT**: added `formats` implicit

```
 import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

 implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

 val m: Map[String, Any] = Map(
   "name "-> "joe",
   "children" -> List(
     Map("name" -> "Mary", "age" -> 5),
     Map("name" -> "Mazy", "age" -> 3)
   )
 )
 // prints {"name ":"joe","children":[{"name":"Mary","age":5},{"name":"Mazy","age":3}]}
 println(Serialization.write(m))
```

Comment: Just for further reference, an implicit `Formats` instance is required, otherwise the following error shows up: `No org.json4s.Formats found. Try to bring an instance of org.json4s.Formats in scope or use the org.json4s.DefaultFormats.`. For instance, `implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats` solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

json4s has method for it.

```
pretty(render(yourMap))
```