# Serialize a Map[String, Any] to JSON where Any includes BigDecimal

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Using Scala 2.10 and json4s 3.5.0, I am trying to serialize a map to a JSON string.  For example:

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats.withBigDecimal
println(Serialization.write(Map("key" -> new java.math.BigDecimal(1)))
```

Fails with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not a primitive class java.math.BigDecimal
```

I followed [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27847784/901330] but the BigDecimal appears to break it.  How do I do this serialization?

Comment: Mapping `Any` is generally a (very) bad idea

Answer (score 1):

`org.json4s.BigDecimalJsonFormats` works for `scala.math.BigDecimal` (Scala BigDecimal) not the Java BigDecimal (java.math.BigDecimal)

So, use `BigDecimal(1)` (Scala BigDecimal)